# How to shows Records entry count one2many field view in odoov8

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo

One2Many and Many2Many the tree view count is not visible if the record is less than 80. And tree view count needed in all cases..
Please any one help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Answer (score 0):

It's code working fine. please try this solution, Thanks You

Path:addons/web/static/src/js/view_list.js

Current:

```
configure_pager: function (dataset) {
    this.dataset.ids = dataset.ids;
    // Not exactly clean
    if (dataset._length) {
        this.dataset._length = dataset._length;
    }

    var total = dataset.size();
    var limit = this.limit() || total;
    if (total === 0)
        this.$pager.hide();
    else
        this.$pager.css("display", "");
    this.$pager.toggleClass('oe_list_pager_single_page', (total <= limit));
    var spager = '-';
    if (total) {
        var range_start = this.page * limit + 1;
        var range_stop = range_start - 1 + limit;
        if (this.records.length) {
            range_stop = range_start - 1 + this.records.length;
        }
        if (range_stop > total) {
            range_stop = total;
        }
        spager = _.str.sprintf(_t("%d-%d of %d"), range_start, range_stop, total);
    }

    this.$pager.find('.oe_list_pager_state').text(spager);
},
```

Changing code:

```
configure_pager: function (dataset) {
    this.dataset.ids = dataset.ids;
    // Not exactly clean
    if (dataset._length) {
        this.dataset._length = dataset._length;
    }
    if (this.$pager) {
        if (this.grouped) {
            // page count is irrelevant on grouped page, replace by limit
            this.$pager.find('.oe-pager-buttons').hide();
            this.$pager.find('.oe_list_pager_state').text(this._limit || '∞');
        } else {
            var total = dataset.size();
            var limit = this._limit || total;
            this.$pager.find('.oe-pager-buttons').toggle(total > limit);
            this.$pager.find('.oe_pager_value').toggle(total !== 0);
            var spager = '-';
            if (total) {
                var range_start = this.page * limit + 1;
                var range_stop = range_start - 1 + limit;
                if (this.records.length) {
                    range_stop = range_start - 1 + this.records.length;
                }
                if (range_stop > total) {
                    range_stop = total;
                }
                spager = _.str.sprintf(_t("%d-%d of %d"), range_start, range_stop, total);
            }

            this.$pager.find('.oe_list_pager_state').text(spager);
        }
    }
},
```